# Repair botched installation of Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, 16.04

I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from the official website, saved the iso on a flashdrive, and made it bootable with Universal USB Installer.  I tried to install it on an HP Compaq dc7600 running Windows XP.  It recognized the flash drive and allowed me to begin the install, but I looked over a couple minutes later and the screen was spazzing out.  It had frozen, and a mesh of perpendicular stripes blinked on the screen.  I couldn't get control back, so I did hard reboot.  The HP logo came up, but no OS logo.  Instead it shows me a black screen with an underscore blinking in the upper left corner.  It's unresponsive to keypress and mouse click.  I can still get into the BIOS, but changing the boot order affects nothing.  I reformatted the USB drive and tried again with Ubuntu, then again with Mint, and still nothing.

Has anyone encountered this before?  Does it sound like there's a hardware issue or perhaps something went wrong when I created the original bootable USB drive?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you can, try recreating the USB media with [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie).

Comment: When you went into bios did  you happen to notice if the hard drive was being recognized?.... just to rule out a drive failure

Answer (score 0):

To make sure it's not your laptop:

1. Check md5sum of your ISO's to check their integrity.
2. Try a different USB. They can be unreliable so it's best to try a few
3. Use another USB installer like unetbootin.